# Other Useful Series Tests

Tags: sequences-and-series, reference-request, soft-question, big-list

So after taking calculus II, or maybe a first course in analysis, everyone learns a few series tests. They learn

1) Divergence Tests

2) Integral Test (from which we deduce things like $p$-series.

3) Comparison Tests

4) Root and Ratio Tests

As well as a few useful theorems pertaining to geometric series, telescoping series, a series-analog to the squeeze theorem. Maybe a few others, but that's all I can come up with off the top of my head for an introductory course. But what other series tests are out there?

I know that there are two tests which are associated, one by Raabe and one by Gauss. Another one called Dirichlet's Test. I get the feeling there are more than just these. Can anyone throw out some others for series of a single variable?

Comment: What did you find when you typed "series convergence" into Google?

Comment: You did not mention http://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy_condensation_test.

Comment: I found calculus II references everywhere. That's why I'm asking here. When I looked for other series, I came across papers and other writings above my level.

Answer (score 2):

Here are some references. The bibliographies in these will lead you to many more references. Based on your comments, Bonar/Khoury's book is probably the best fit for you right now.

Bonar/Khoury, [**Real Infinite Series**](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0883857456) (2006)

Bromwich, [**An Introduction to the Theory of Infinite Series**](https://archive.org/details/introductiontoth00bromuoft) (1908) [a 1925 2nd edition also exists]

Hirschman, [**Infinite Series**](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0486789756) (1962/2014)

Knopp, [**Theory and Application of Infinite Series**](https://archive.org/details/theoryandapplica031692mbp) (1954)

Knopp, [**Infinite Sequences and Series**](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0486601536) (1956)

Osgood, [**Introduction to Infinite Series**](https://archive.org/details/introinfiniteser00osgorich) (1897)

Rainville, [**Infinite Series**](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B0006BOHBQ) (1967)