# Survey of (advanced) series summation tricks and techniques

Tags: sequences-and-series, reference-request, summation

I am looking for a good survey of techniques of summation of series.

Trying to search for this, I can only find undergraduate course notes covering very elementary series (geometric, telescoping, etc.). It would be very nice to have a reference for seasoned mathematicians, that goes into more depth and discusses more techniques -- something similar to Krattenthaller's [survey](https://arxiv.org/abs/math/9902004) on determinant calculations.
Is there any such thing?

Comment: Mary Boas' Mathematical Methods in the Physical Sciences is probably a good mid-level text. I learned The Method of Froebenius from there. Was never mentioned in my math degree courses. Numerical Recipes is a classic covering the math AND numerical methods. Much of the latter is available for free.

Comment: See **An Introduction to the Operations with Series** by Isaac Joachim Schwatt (1924; reprinted with corrections by Chelsea Publishing Company in 1962). A [google-books .pdf file for the 1924 edition](https://books.google.com/books?id=IJttAAAAMAAJ) is freely available where I'm at. Also, the Internet Archive has the [1924 edition](https://archive.org/details/anintroductionto0000ijsc) for download and the [1962 Chelsea edition](https://archive.org/details/introductiontoop00schw_0) for borrowing.

Comment: See also the books listed in my answer to [Other Useful Series Tests](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/984345/13130).